# How to remove the already iterated rows of a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop

I have a csv file with 100 records. I want to write the first 50 records in a new csv file i.e 'newFile.csv' in the first iteration. In the second iteration, I want to write the next 50 records in the 'newFile.csv' file after reading the next 50 records from the original csv file.

I am able to perform the first Iteration but unable to perform the second iteration with the expected values as the next 50 rows that has to be written in the csv file.
Can someone please help me out in this?? Thank you

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd

oldData = pd.read_csv('oldFile.csv') # Has 100 rows

for i in range(2):
    newData = pd.read_csv('oldFile.csv', nrows=50) # Has 50 rows

    newCsv = newData.to_csv('newFile.csv', index=False)

    newData = newData.iloc[50:] # Removes those 50 rows
```

Comment: Could you explain why do you try to achieve ?
I would understand if at the end your goal was to obtain `newFile1.csv` and `newFile2.csv`, containg respectively the first 50 rows and the last 50 rows.

Comment: @fbattello I don't want to have newFile1,newFile2 and newFIle_n. Reading from 1 csv file containing about 100 records, I want to write 50 records in a new csv file and then I want to overwrite the next 50 records in the same csv file. Thank you

Comment: Understood, technically. I suppose at some point in your loop you call a function like this one`process_csv_file(newCsv)`. Do you try to achieve some kind of batch operation, with batch size equals to 50 rows ?

Comment: Yes you are right, I will be calling the function @fbattello

Comment: Is it mandatory to write to disk all these files ? Or does you processing function just need to be called with bunches of 50 rows ? Is pandas mandatory ?

Comment: Like I have to convert those 50 records into a json file and then pass it to the http request. The maximum I can pass is 50 records. Is there any other way other than pandas I can do it?? Thank you @fbattello

Comment: If the goal is something like "send as many HTTP POST requests as needed to a server that accepts a max batchsize of 50 records". Then it's complicated and inefficient to use the disk. `pandas` is a library dedicated to data science and may not be the best suited tool.

Comment: Yes @0x0fba Like once I get those 50 records , I am converting them into json and then uploading it to the http request. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

oldData = pd.read_csv('oldFile.csv') # Has 100 rows

for newData in pd.read_csv('oldFile.csv', chunksize=50) # Has 50 rows:

    newCsv = newData.to_csv('newFile.csv', index=False)

    newData = newData.iloc[50:] # Removes those 50 rows
```

In this way each time you read the .csv file it contains 50 rows. The first iteration the first 50 rows, the second one the rows from 51 to 101, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the `oldFile.csv` in chunks of 50 rows and then process each chunk individually, e.g.,

```
import pandas as pd

nRows=50

with pd.read_csv('oldFile.csv', chunksize=nRows, header=None) as reader:
    for chunk in reader:
        print(chunk)
        chunk.to_csv('newFile.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

Note that `newFile.csv` is being overwritten on each iteration.